# Lambda expression - List to Map

Tags: java, lambda

I want to transform a list of String to a map, where the key of map is a simple increment.

For example:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
result.add("hello");
result.add("Java");
```

Pretend result:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapOfList;
map(1, "Hello");
map(2, "Java");
```

Try:

```
AtomicInteger atomic=new AtomicInteger(0);
mapOfList=result.stream().collect(atomic.incrementAndGet(), s -> s);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
result.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(element -> atomic.incrementAndGet(), Function.identity());
```

Comment: Functions should generally be stateless, although documentation doesn't say it explicitly in this case. `atomic` is effectively a state of a `keyMapper` function here. If you changed it to parallel stream it would mess up the ids.